# How to make all nodes in a line when using netchart of zoomcharts

Tags: zoomcharts

[In the pic that all node not in a line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjoXZ.png)

I want all the nodes in a line within the netcharts,not incline as showed in pic.
Which property of zoomcharts is used for disable incline?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Make all nodes in a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w9Dd.png)

I found that using `direction` to make all nodes in a line.Just make direction consistent with `from ... to...`

```
"links":[
            {"from":"a", "to":"b","style":{"toDecoration":"arrow","direction":"R"}},
            {"from":"b", "to":"c", "style":{"toDecoration":"arrow", "direction":"R"}},
            {"from":"a", "to":"a_child1","style":{"toDecoration":"arrow","direction":"L"}},
            {"from":"c", "to":"c_child1","style":{"toDecoration":"arrow","direction":"R"}}
        ]
```

a_child1 <- a -> b -> c -> c_child1